# Advagg breaks the site for logged in users

Tags: theming

Recently started having issues with Advagg module.

If I set the AdvAgg Cache Settings to anything other than Development, it breaks the site (one of the CSS file goes in redirect loop).

Only happens for logged in users and on certain pages. I recently changed my.cnf so I am thinking it might be due to slow response from database which causes Advagg to miss the file and it goes into a loop.

Unfortunately I don't have the copy of previous my.cnf.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong.

Comment: Explain precisely what you mean by “one of the CSS file goes in redirect loop”, how you detected that, which file, and provide specific details.

Comment: Thanks @cilefen - I get the following error in the browser: Failed to load resource: Load cannot follow more than 20 redirections .. On network tab, I see lots of files with ?redirect_counter=1 appended.

Comment: If you're asking people to guess what might be wrong, you really need to share your actual configuration, preferably the YAML export of advagg settings.